# preg_replace question

Tags: php, preg-replace

Hello I'm trying to do the following:

Say I have an input string like this

```
{stackoverflow is a {cool|great} website|stackoverflow is the {best|greatest}}. {stackoverflow is for {cool|great} coders|stackoverflow is the {best|greatest} site for coders}
```

How can I convert it to the following format by using PHP

```
{stackoverflow is a [cool|great] website~stackoverflow is the [best|greatest]}. {stackoverflow is for [cool|great] coders~stackoverflow is the [best|greatest] site for coders}
```

I'm playing with preg_replace but I can't find a working solution.

To sum things up:
The nested { should be turn into [.

And the | on the first level should turn into ~.

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Is this homework? What do you have so far?

Comment: Is there a general pattern you have in mind? Your example is very specific.

Comment: Well my main problem is the nesting. If i could get an array or so with stackoverflow is a {cool|great} website and stackoverflow is the {best|greatest} as values it would be quite easy to fix the rest.

Comment: For the array, you could so `preg_split('/\|(?![a-z]+})/', substr($subject, 1, -1))` which splits on the vertical pipes which aren't within curly braces (strictly, aren't followed by letters and a curly brace).

Answer (score 0):

no need for preg_replace ;)

```
$value = '{stackoverflow is a {cool|great} website|stackoverflow is the {best|greatest}}';
$map = array( '{' => '[', '}' => ']', '~' => '|' );
$value = '{' . str_replace( array_keys($map), array_values($map), substr($value, 1, -1) ) . '}';
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work...

Did an echo on $value, and it spit out this:

{stackoverflow is a [cool|great] website|stackoverflow is the [best|greatest}

Comment: whoops sorry about that, should of tested - sorted now :)